# Getting a image data source from a span with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to extract the "`data-img-url`" value from the span in the a class.  But I am not succeeding.

```
<div class="td-module-container td-category-pos-image">
   <div class="td-image-container">
      <a href="https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/category/ciencia-e-ambiente/" class="td-post-category">Ciência, Tecnologia e Ambiente</a>                        
      <div class="td-module-thumb"><a href="https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/destaque/ensaio-clinico-determina-resposta-imunologica-contra-covid-19/" rel="bookmark" class="td-image-wrap " title="Ensaio clínico determina resposta imunológica contra Covid-19"><span class="entry-thumb td-thumb-css td-animation-stack-type0-2" data-type="css_image" data-img-url="https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/INS-485x360.jpg" data-img-retina-url="https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/INS-970x662.jpg" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/INS-970x662.jpg&quot;)"></span></a></div>
   </div>
   <div class="td-module-meta-info">
      <h3 class="entry-title td-module-title"><a href="https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/destaque/ensaio-clinico-determina-resposta-imunologica-contra-covid-19/" rel="bookmark" title="Ensaio clínico determina resposta imunológica contra Covid-19">Ensaio clínico determina ...</a></h3>
      <div class="td-editor-date">
         <span class="td-author-date">
         <span class="td-post-author-name"><a href="https://www.jornalnoticias.co.mz/author/amandio/">Amandio Roberto Macuácua</a> <span>-</span> </span>                                    <span class="td-post-date"><time class="entry-date updated td-module-date" datetime="2021-12-28T02:29:00+00:00">28 de Dezembro, 2021</time></span>                                                                                                        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="td-excerpt">
         O ENSAIO clínico de comb...
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My source code is as follows:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_ = "td-module-container td-category-pos-image"):

    name = div.find('a', class_ = "td-image-wrap")['title']

    print(name)

    url = div.find('a', class_ = "td-image-wrap", href=True)["href"]

    print(url)

    image = div.find('span', class_ = "entry-thumb td-thumb-css td-animation-stack-type0-2")["data-img-url"]

    print(image)

    date = div.find('time', class_ = 'entry-date updated td-module-date').text

    print(date)

    article = Article(name=name, url=url, image=image['data-img-url'], date=date)

    latest.articles.append(article)
```

My error is as follows:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

It is obviously not finding the span that I am looking for, but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', class_="td-module-container td-category-pos-image"):
    print(div.find('span', class_="entry-thumb").get('data-img-url'))
```

Comment: @Sergey K - Keep in mind to provide some more context to an answer , so that is clear why things happens or not and everybody could reproduce and learn from- Would be great

Answer (score 0):

To extract the "data-img-url" value from the range in class a, without encountering the NoneType error anymore, try writing like this:

```
div.find('span', class_="entry-thumb").get("data-img-url")
```